# Bootstrap columns add to 12 but are still wrapping

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap row that has columns that add to twelve. Taking the col-mds out of context, they are:

```
class="col-md-1 control-label"
class="col-md-2"
class="col-md-1 control-label"
class="col-md-2"
class="col-md-1 control-label"
class="col-md-1"
class="col-md-1"
class="col-md-1 control-label"
class="col-md-1"
class="col-md-1"
```

=12!!!

Yet the second read-only field is wrapping for some reason. Does anyone have any insight as to why this would happen?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qrzb2ann/

Comment: You're having 12 columns. Good. however, at some places you're using `col-md-1` and at some places, you're using `col-md-2`. The thing is `col-md-1` and `col-md-2` take up `1 + 2 = 3` columns. :)

Comment: So in your code, there are `1+2+1+2+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=14` columns. It exceeds 12 so the last 2 columns get wrapped around. :)

Comment: idk how that guy counted 14, i got 12. your code looks fine. however, you realize that "md-*" classes only apply to mid sized viewport. if you want it to look like that on small screens you need to add "sm-*" classes, and likewise for large and extra large screens.

Comment: @Pamblam Thanks for confirming that I'm not going crazy adding those columns. I am looking at it on a md sized viewport, and even adding sm- and lg- classes is not fixing the wrapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 extra `label`s in you markup that aren't `col-*` so it's throwing off the spacing (although for me it's not wrapping).

I don't think you need to have empty labels. If you want to keep them use `pull-left` so that they float:left and don't effect the grid.

`<label class="pull-left"></label>`

http://www.bootply.com/CxMOq6ARs3

**EDIT:** Each input should have labels so as described in the docs so use the `sr-only` classes on the empty labels so that they don't effect the grid columns.

Comment: Yes, those are readonly fields. I read that every field should have a "label" even if it is empty. Why would it throw off the spacing without the `col-*` since technically those "labels" aren't taking up any space?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Taking out the empty labels fixed the problem. However I did check for future users and Bootstrap docs do specify to keep the label: "Always add labels
Screen readers will have trouble with your forms if you don't include a label for every input. For these input groups, ensure that any additional label or functionality is conveyed to assistive technologies.
The exact technique to be used ... will vary..." I will use your pull-left suggestion

Comment: Yes, you're right and the docs continue on to say use the `sr-only` class so they only show on screen readers.